# Getting a model's app_label from within its Meta subclass

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override a model's `db_table` with configuration like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "app_label_table_name"
```

However, I would like the `app_label` to be accessed programmatically.

Generally, I can do: `MyModel._meta.app_label`. However, I'm not having any luck getting at that property from within the Meta old-style class scope.

- `self.app_label` doesn't work, because `self` doesn't seem to exist in that context.
- `MyModel._meta.app_label` doesn't work either, probably because `MyModel` hasn't been defined yet.

How can I get the `app_label` programmatically from within this context? Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Can you reference the module directly? .__module__

Comment: Hey that's a good idea. Why not add it as an answer? Any idea why `app_label` exists alongside `__module__`? Are they not always one-to-one?

Comment: Although `__module__` gets me `app_label.models`. I'd have to stip off `models`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the django source, the `app_label` is pulled from the `__module__` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py) attribute. The source is using meta classes and pulls the `__module__` from the arguments attrs passed to that meta class definition. It is beyond me what that actually means, but for all intents and purposes it looks like `app_label` and `__module__` will be the same in this case.